# magento2 create translation pack

Tags: magento2, language-package

After reading the complete translation documentation ([here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html)), I still have some questions / problems. The end goal is to create translations for my magento2 installation.

I run the following [command](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-dict) to create a translation dictionary:

> php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "translations.csv" -m
>   c:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\

Where `magento2` is the root path of my magento installation. Please note the `-m` that is required to build a translation pack. If I ommit this parameter, the generated output is 400kb+ (but it contains only 2 columns). If I add the parameter, I only get a 4kb file (it contains the correct 3 columns format). Am I missing something here?

Pastebin (with `-m`): http://pastebin.com/ssCMaKGw

Pastebin (without `-m`): http://pastebin.com/cfJGT2tS

Then for a theme translation, I can ommit the -m parameter and after I made the translations for the default `luma` theme, it's not replacing anything. I've changed my locale in administration to the correct one and also flush cache, rebuilt indexes.

> php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases
>   -o "app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/i18n/nl_NL.csv" app/design/frontend/Magento/luma

Comment: How many rows do you have in each file? With `-m` and without?

Comment: 6761 without -m, 29 with -m. I'll add some pastebins to the question.

Comment: We just merged a fix related to this tool, please check it. Also, behavior or `-m` flag has been modified. Please stand by for doc changes related to that.

Comment: I will try it out tomorrow and keep you up to date. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: The updated command is available on the develop branch. The change was to redefine `-m` as searching the Magento codebase. The optional `pack` parameter was removed also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm the -m command is working now with the updates that were committed on the development branch. Thanks for this @steve-johnson & @maddy.

Generated a 762Kb file.